# Unity - Selective Collisions - Again

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I know this subject has been discussed here a bunch of times already. But I'm stuck here.

I am developing a simple game where I have a few rigid bodies piled and a projectile is intended to hit those gameObjects.

But some of those rigid bodies are collectibles, elements that give points if hit with the projectile.

My question is: I need those collectibles to behave just like the other rigid bodies, but as a trigger for the projectile.

How can I do it?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not one hundred percent sure I understand what you want, but here is what I think you need to be doing.

Set a tag on the collectible called "Collectible"
And then in the code write the following

```
Void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other){
    if(other.tag == "Collectible"){
        CollectCollectible();
    }
}
```

OnCollisionEnter is run whenever something collides with the object, checking a tag is far from the most effecient way of doing this, but it's probably the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you right. Attach a Script to the collectibles and let it implement `OnCollisionEnter`. If you don't know which ones are the collectibles at design time, you can do it at runtime via `AddComponent <MyCollectibleScript> ()`.

Another (pretty dirty) way is to take different physic materials but this just for the sake of completeness.